# How do I search a string from a file and return the line location using functions in C++?

Tags: c++, file-handling, string-search

I am trying to make a program that lets me search for groups of words in a file and then it would return the line locations where they are found. I made it work for a little bit but for some reason, the value of **int FileLine** (line location) keeps on stacking up whenever a new word search is introduced.

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string S1, S2, S, Line;
int FileLine = 0;

int CountInFile(string S) {
    ifstream in("DataFile.txt");
    while (getline(in, Line)) {
        FileLine++;
        if (Line.find(S, 0) != string::npos) {
            cout << "Found " << S << " at line " << FileLine << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
    in.close();
}


int main()
{
    // Words to search
    CountInFile("Computer Science");
    CountInFile("Programming");
    CountInFile("C++");
    CountInFile("COSC");
    CountInFile("computer");
```

This is the output:

[image: Output image]

Is there a way that I can stop the FileLine value from stacking?

Comment: Stacking? The multiple lines? Or you want the search to start from the beginning each time? You don't need globals in this program.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, I want to search from the beginning each time. I am currently doing this for homework and my professor requires me to use globals for it.

Comment: So add `FileLine = 0;` at the top of `CountInFile`. But really, it should be a local variable in `CountInFile` to begin with. How come you are allowed to use `in` as a local variable, but not any others?

Comment: The global is exactly why you're having an issue. When the function ends, its value is unchanged. Any professor requiring the use of globals in a basic program like this is one worth speaking with the department chair about.

Comment: I expect to see `FileLine = 0;` more than once. The variable is initialized, but after every search or before the next one, it needs to be set back to zero. Requiring the use of global variables is a terrible lesson unless the professor's built boobytraps into the lesson to teach why you should not use them. That would improve the lesson to merely bad.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much for your comment. I finally made it to work! you were right. I needed to localize FileLine=0.

Comment: FYI, any statements after `return` are not executed.  Think about it.  How can statements be executed after execution leaves the function.  Example:  `return 0; in.close();`

Comment: Please refrain from posting pictures of outputs/code as much as possible. Just copy paste the output.